# codeigniter $this->save() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04, datamapper

I recently started using codeigniter. trying to create a new model for a new table. It seems save() method is not working properly. I am not able to see new records in my table.I did some research over net and stackoverflow, but no use. Can someone please check my code and advice.

```js
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  2 
  3 class Listing_Price_History extends DataMapper
  4 {
  5 
  6     var $table = 'listing_price_history';
  7     var $primary_key = 'id';
  8     var $primary_key_suffix = '_uid';
  9 
 10 
 11     // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 12         /** Validations for the requried fields */
 13     var $validation = array(
 14         'listing_id' => array(
 15                 'label' => 'Listing Id',
 16                 'rules' => array('required')
 17         ),
 18         'price_per_sqft' => array(
 19                 'label' => 'Price per square feet',
 20                 'rules' => array('required')
 21         )
 22     );
 23 
 24     // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 25 
 26     public function __construct() {
 27         parent::__construct();
 28         $CI =& get_instance();
 29         $CI->load->library('uuid');
 30         $this->uuid = $CI->uuid;
 31         $CI->load->helper('company');
 32 
 33     }
 34 
 35     // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 36 
 37     // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 38 
 39     /**
 40      * Create listing entry
41      *
 42      * @return bool
 43      **/
 44     public function savePriceHistory($history) {
 45           //  var_dump($history); 
 46           //  var_dump($this);
 47             if(isset($history['listing_id']))
 48               $this->listing_id = $history['listing_id'];
 49             if(isset($history['price_per_sqft']))
 50               $this->price_per_sqft = $history['price_per_sqft'];
 51             $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 52             $this->created_by = $this->uuid;
 53             $this->created_date = $date;
 54             $save_history = $this->save();
 55           //  var_dump($this->check_last_query());
 56           //  var_dump($this->db->_error_message());
 57           //  var_dump($this->db->_error_number());
 58           //  var_dump($save_history);
 59     }
 60 }
                                                                                                                              60,1          Bot
```

Controller: 
This is how I am calling model

```js
 432             if($status){
 433               echo "Entered";
 434               $price_history = new Listing_Price_History();
 435               $save_history =  $price_history->savePriceHistory($history);
 436               echo $save_history;
 437               echo "Finished";
 438             }
```

this is my table structure

[image]

please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: what is this `$this->save();` ?? Are you calling model on here ??

Comment: this is ORM method right? to save/insert record to table

Comment: Are you sing any 3rd party CURD library/helper  ?? what you mean by this  
`this is ORM method right?`

Comment: Correct. We are using DataMapper, which has this inbuilt method to save records to database.

Comment: are you using this ??https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper

Comment: No. Can you please check pasted code and advice if there is any wrong?

Comment: Make sure this is calling. `$this->save()` cz when 3rd party library its hard to debug

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your model with:

```php
protected $useAutoIncrement = false;
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue from time to time and have to remind myself that on some codeigniter systems datamapper creates files in the cache directory that it uses to keep database table meta-data.  If you add a column to the database it won't automatically be accessible if a cache file exists.

So in codeigniter go to the app/cache directory and remove the file with the same name as your table.  You should find that it is rebuilt the first time you use it with the new table schema and that it will all work

Answer (score 0):

For People, who are facing these issue nowadays:
try add to table model another property, primaryKey, like below:

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

It helped me.
Codeigniter 4 save() method should be aware, what column is your key, especially, if column name is different than typical 'id' name.
In my case, table's id was exactly 'user_id' and that was a problem.